# redirect_to and :controller, :actions getting mixed up in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails controller I'm calling this:

```
redirect_to :controller => "user", :action => "login"
```

My `user_controller.rb` defines the following method:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def login
  ###
  end
```

When I call my `redirect_to` method I get this error in my browser: `No action responded to show.` Checking the server logs I see this line:

```
Processing UserController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-19 12:11:53) [GET] 
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"login", "controller"=>"user"}
```

Finally, I've got this line in my `routes.rb`

```
map.resources :user
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hack-y answer is to change the following line in your routes.rb

`map.resources :user`

to

`map.resources :user, :collection => { :login => :get }`

But that's bad for a variety of reasons -- mainly because it breaks the RESTful paradigm. Instead, you should use a SessionController and use `sessions/new` to login. You can alias it to `/login` by the following line in routes.rb

`map.login 'login', :controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"`

Comment: +1 but I don't think it's such a big deal to break the restful paradigm. The universe contains more than 4 verbs. :-)

Comment: My answer was functionally the same as this, I think. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Tried

```
redirect_to :url => {:action => 'login', :controller => 'user'}
```

Or you might have to remove the routing or write your own. The routing maps POST to create, PUT to update etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `login` action in your routes.rb. Refer to [this excellent guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a new `login_controller` to handle logins.

Here's the relavent bit from my routes.rb file:

```
map.login '/login', :controller => 'login', :action => 'login'
```

Thanks for your help...